# XSL: 'Moving' following-siblings without duplicating

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given the XML:

```
<root>
    <txto>Header text<txto>
    <txt>more paragraph text</txt>
    <txt>even more paragraph text</txt>
    <txto>Another header<txto>
    <txt> … </txt>
    <txt> … </txt>
</root>
```

The desired output is having the first header define a section, while preserving the second:

```
<root>
    <n1>
        <o>Header text</o>
        <txt>more paragraph text</txt>
        <txt>even more paragraph text</txt>
    </n1>
    <txto>Another header<txto>
    <txt> … </txt>
    <txt> … </txt>
</root>
```

Using the XSL:

```
<xsl:template match=“//txto[starts-with(., ‘Header’)]”>         
    <n1>
        <o><xsl:value-of select="."/></o>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::txt" />     
    </n1>     
</xsl:template>
```

However, the result is 'duplication' of the txt elements:

```
<root>
    <n1>
        <o>Header text</o>
        <txt>more paragraph text</txt>
        <txt>even more paragraph text</txt>
    </n1>
    <txt>more paragraph text</txt>       <-- 'duplicated'
    <txt>even more paragraph text</txt>  <-- 'duplicated'
    <txto>Another header<txto>
    <txt> … </txt>
    <txt> … </txt>
</root>
```

Which probably has to do with the Identity transform already having copied all txt nodes to the result tree:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

How do I avoid copying the two 'duplicated' txt nodes to the result tree? I only want them inside the n1 node and not immediately after.

Comment: "The desired output is having the first header define a section": why don't you use a template `match="texto[1]"` then? Or how do you define a "header" and which is the first? Also, which version of XSLT do you use?

Comment: The txto nodes need to be matched by their content, not position. XSLT version is preferably 1.0 - but might be able to make 2.0 work

Comment: In XSLT 2 I would use `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="texto[starts-with., 'Header')]"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="position() = 1"><n1>...</n1></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:for-each-group>`. For XSLT you can select only those elements which have the right preceding sibling, see several similar questions recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **XSLT 1.0** you could do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="following-txt" match="txt" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::txto[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="txto"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="txto[starts-with(., 'Header')]">
    <n1>
        <o>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </o>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('following-txt', generate-id())"/>
    </n1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="txto">
    <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('following-txt', generate-id())"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow! That works - even though I'm struggling to realize what's going on :-)

Comment: Think of it as hitching wagons to a locomotive.

Comment: It seems my Identity transform copies the <txt> to the result tree. Is there any way I can suppress that using the generated key?

Comment: My XSLT does not use the Identity transform. I don't know how to combine this with something I cannot see.

Comment: Understandable. My actual XML is more complicated, with much of the XML merely needing to be cloned to the result document. So I wonder if there is a way to prevent my Identity transform from handling the <txt> marked by the key?

Comment: <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: If you don't want the nodes to be handled by the Identity transform template, then don't apply the Identity transform template to them. In my example, the template matching `root` applies templates only to `txto` elements. Even if you added the Identity transform template, it would not be applied to any other child of `root`.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2 or 3:

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="txto[starts-with(., 'Header')]">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                      <n1>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </n1>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="txto[starts-with(., 'Header')][1]">
      <o>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </o>
  </xsl:template>
```

That assumes there are several `txto` elements starting with `Header`, it is not quite sure why your code checks for that but your sample for the "second" header has an element `<txto>Another header<txto>` that does not meet that condition.

Based on your comment, although I still think your requirement is clear, you might simply want a pattern `group-starting-with="txto"` for the `for-each-group` and a pattern `match="txto[1]"` for the transformation template below.

In XSLT 1 an approach like

```
  <xsl:key name="sibling-group" 
           match="root/*[not(self::txto)]" 
           use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::txto[1])"/>
           
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
           
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="txto"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="txto[1]">
      <n1>
          <o>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </o>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sibling-group', generate-id())"/>
      </n1>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="txto[not(position() = 1)]">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sibling-group', generate-id())"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

could work, again, the conditions might be adapted or enhanced to precisely select what a "header" is.

Comment: It seems to me that the grouping includes all txto and txt:

Comment: <root>
   <n1>
      <o>Header text</o>
      <txt>more paragraph text</txt>
      <txt>even more paragraph text</txt>
      <txto>Another header</txto>
      <txt> … </txt>
      <txt> … </txt>
   </n1>
</root>

Comment: It seems I need to use following-sibling to avoid going past the second <txto>

Comment: @morsor, I think, at least to me, it is not clear what you consider a header, in your sample you check for `txto[starts-with(., 'Header')]`, you only have a single element of that condition in your sample input. However, in your input you then only have `<txto>Another header<txto>` but speak about "while preserving the second". So whether it is grouping or using `<<` or `>>` or a condition on the following sibling, you first need to clarify what constitutes a "header".

Comment: Ahh - OK. Only the first header should be matched. The purpose is to 'group' the first <txto> and its following-sibling <txt> - but leave the following <txto> and <txt> untouched